# How to run through a loop multiple times in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Ok i modified my code but cannot get it to break when the user inputs 0. I tried 0, '0', and "0" and neither break the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
int word;
int countword = 0;
int countpunct = 0;
do{
    printf("\nEnter the String: ");
    while ((word = getchar()) != EOF && word != '\n'){
        if (word == ' ' || word == '.' || word == '?' || word == '!' || word == '(' || word == ')' || word == '*' || word == '&'){
            countword++;
        }
        if (word == '.' || word == '?' || word == '!' || word == '(' || word == ')' || word == '*' || word == '&'){
            countpunct++;
        }
    }
    printf("\nThe number of words is %d.", countword);

    printf("\nThe number of punctuation marks is %d.", countpunct);

} while (word!= 0);

}
```

Comment: `scanf("%c", word);` will not work. Replace with `scanf("%c", &word);` And why are you using `getchar` one time and `scanf` the other?

Comment: Weird formatting... continue get a K&R style brace on the if line and one below it, but return 0 doesn't get any braces.

Comment: There is no need to `continue` to continue from the bottom of an infinite loop to the next iteration, though it's harmless.  That's what would happen anyway.

Comment: You should ahve a look at `do ... while` loops. (Note: `word` is actually a `char` and should be declared as such (and the name should reflect its meaning; a word would be expected to be a string).

Comment: would a do while loop replace the entire for(;;) loop or would it go on the for(;;) loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner loops break when `word` is either `EOF` or `\n`.  Since you never modify it when you get to the end of the outer loop, the condition will always be true.

Going back to your pre-edit code, all you really need is to change `scanf("%c", word);` to `scanf("%c", &word);`, although you should use a separate `char` variable for that, since the `%c` format specifier expected a pointer to `char`.  So your code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int word;
    char cont;
    for (;;){
        int countword = 0;
        int countpunct = 0;
        printf("\nEnter the String: ");
        while ((word = getchar()) != EOF && word != '\n'){
            if (word == ' ' || word == '.' || word == '?' || word == '!' || word == '(' || word == ')' || word == '*' || word == '&'){
                countword++;
            }
            if (word == '.' || word == '?' || word == '!' || word == '(' || word == ')' || word == '*' || word == '&'){
                countpunct++;
            }
        }
        printf("\nThe number of words is %d.", countword);

        printf("\nThe number of punctuation marks is %d.", countpunct);

        printf("\nContinue? Y/N?");
        scanf("%c", &cont);
        if (cont!= 'y' && cont!= 'Y'){
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Note also that `countword` and `countpunct` are moved inside of the outer loop.  That way, they're initialized to 0 for each new set of words.